# BootstrapVue insert image inside b-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I'm looking for the solution how to display an image inside b-table cell.

My template:

```
<template v-slot:cell(foto)="data">
   <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" :src="data.item.foto" alt="..." />                 
</template>
```

Photos *foto* field:

```
{ key: "foto", label: "Image", sortable: false, editable: true },
```

Foto field in the items:

```
{ id: 4, name: 'apple', foto: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Red_Apple.jpg/220px-Red_Apple.jpg'},
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I can see only the URL to the image, not the image itself.
I think that the problem may be related to the fact that b-table escapes HTML tags, but I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Yes, I am using Vue CLI. Unfortunately it didn't resolve an issue, here it is my app: [link]https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wescoff-o5x65?file=/components/DataTable.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it fails in your project link is because you are defining the template content for `fotografia` twice:  once for `fotografia` specifically, and again in a `v-for` which handles all elements.

Remove this:

```html
<template v-slot:cell(foto)="data">
   <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" :src="data.item.foto" alt="..." />            
</template>
```

And use this for your `v-for`:

```html
<template  v-for="field in editableFields"
           v-slot:[`cell(${field.key})`]="{ value, item}"
           >
  <b-input v-if="itemRow && itemRow.id === item.id" 
           v-model="itemRow[field.key]" :key="field.key"
           :type="field.type || 'text'" 
           :number="field.isNumber"
           >
  </b-input>
  <!-- now there is a condition for fields that have `image: true` -->
  <template v-else-if="field.image"><img :src="item.foto" /></template>
  <template v-else>{{ value }}</template>
</template>
```

And add `image: true` to your `foto` field:

```js
{ key: "foto", label: "Image", sortable: false, editable: true, image: true },
```